# Update several values from several ID's

Tags: mysql, select, update

I have a SELECT request - it works fine:

```
select meta_value
from wp_posts v
left join wp_postmeta pm on (pm.post_id = v.id)
left join wp_posts p on (v.post_parent = p.id)
where meta_key in ('_price','_regular_price')
and v.post_type = 'product_variation'
and p.id = '1743'
limit 0,100
```

Request find several post's meta_value relative to post with id = 1743.

It returns me 4 (four) needed fields with values like

```
400
500
300
350
```

I need an UPDATE request for it.

I try

```
Update wp_posts 
set meta_value = 1000
where id IN (select v.id
            from wp_posts v
            left join wp_postmeta pm on (pm.post_id = v.id)
            left join wp_posts p on (v.post_parent = p.id)
            where meta_key in ('_price','_regular_price')
                and v.post_type = 'product_variation'
                and p.id = '1743')
```

But it cause error

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'FROM wp_posts WHERE meta_key in ( 'price' , '_regular_price' )
>   and v.post' at line 2

This function as a part of UPDATE

```
select v.id
from wp_posts v
left join wp_postmeta pm on (pm.post_id = v.id)
left join wp_posts p on (v.post_parent = p.id)
where meta_key in ('_price','_regular_price')
and v.post_type = 'product_variation'
and p.id = '1743'
```

Returns me right ID'S like

1744 1744 1745 1745

But UPDATE function with this select make an error.

There is mistake??? Help me please

Comment: The error doesn't match the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug or maybe lack of functionality in various versions of MariaDB/MySQL that prevents update of a table that's part of a sub-select. Small example:

```
create table A (x int not null, y int not null);
insert into A (x,y) values (1,1),(2,2),(3,3);
update A set y = 5 where x in ( 
    select x from A where y in (1,2) 
);
ERROR 1093 (HY000): Table 'A' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data
```

You can fool the DBMS by hiding the table in a nested table

```
update A 
    set y = 5 
where x in (
    select x from ( 
        select x from A where y in (1,2) 
    ) as T 
);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

MySQL on the other hand supports a non standard update where you can update a join, but since you did not provide create table statements I'll leave that out of the answer (I'm too lazy to figure out what your tables look like :-)

Comment: Found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057565/mysql-update-statement-inner-join-tables) with JOIN